# How to Rotate Card Image in Flutter by User Dragging Movement or Automatically Based on The Card Edges

Tags: image, flutter, camera, rotation, photo

So i know how to capture photo (either by using camera or image_picker), I know how to crop those images in a certain square/ rectangle dimension, and I know how to put a rotate button with certain angle functionality (e.g. rotate 90 degree or 180 degree).

But I would like to know how to rotate captured image based on user dragging movement.
So if for example there is an id card that slant 20 degree, I will be able to drag it and make it straight.

Or, if there is any method to auto detect the frame of id card and rotate it automatically?
I have tried edge_detection and flutter_realtime_detection libs, but edge_detection didn't detect the edge properly, especially if there are other images in the background of the card; flutter_realtime_detection also falsely detect my id card as book, put way big distance between the edges and how they frame.
And I don't think it's using Transform widget as well.
Can you please help me to know how can i do it? Thanks.

Edit: I've found the rotate using finger gesture in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/17345
What I need now is the auto-detect and auto-rotate id card frame part.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: for my understanding, you want something like a slider where the user can rotate the image based on the slider value

Comment: Yes, correct @dstreissi =)
Sorry I think I've found that one on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/17345
What I haven't found is the auto detect the frame of id card part.